# Unrecognized option "form_login" under "security.firewalls.main"

Tags: symfony, security, fosuserbundle, firewall

I'm using Symfony 3.0.4 and FOSUserBundle 2.0.

When I try to configure my security like the symfony doc:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

I have an error :

```
InvalidConfigurationException in ArrayNode.php line 317:
Unrecognized option "form_login" under "security.firewalls.main"
```

What is the problem ? `form_login` just seems to be an option...

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Trash but I have just removed the `vendor/symfony` folder and run a `composer update`.
Now it's working.

Comment: I've spent the afternoon trying to figure that same exact error out. Only that could some it.